# Disable "update links message" when opening MS Excel via VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing an auto-run macro, but it is password protected. After I removed all the passwords, it can save the file in a different format.

The thing is that MS Excel displays a Popup Message about "update links automatically". I Tried to disable all settings from MS Excel options but the dialog still appearing.

So, I was thinking to add some code to avoid that popup.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Test\WorkbookTest.xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.UnprotectSharing ("galleta")
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("galleta")
    ChDir "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Reportes"
    Sheets("BES").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("galleta")
    Sheets("BE800").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("galleta")
    Sheets("BECM").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("galleta")   
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Reportes\test.mht", FileFormat:= _
        xlWebArchive, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I placed my autorun with the password thing code because it may help to someone.

Other data:

- Office 2007,
- Windows Server 2008 R2.

The message is appearing to protect the user's platform, but may be we can configure the user preference forehand via [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument to Workbooks.Open is UpdateLinks.  Set it to False:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Test\WorkbookTest.xlsx",False
```